# how to display a bullet list using ionic framework?

Tags: css, layout, ionic-framework

Using ionic to build an app, and I have a need to display an actual bullet list:

- item 1
- item 2
- item 3

However, it appears that the framework does some sort of CSS reset / magic on `<ul>` and `<li>` elements such that they should only be used as structure elements (e.g. a list), rather  than as UI.

I ended up creating my own `unordered-list` CSS style to give me the UI I needed. Is that the right way to do-it-yourself - or does ionic have some CSS style buried deep inside that I should have used instead?

ty in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just overwrite the reset.

```
ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

Like this (place in your CSS after the CSS of the framework)

```
ul {
  list-style-type: disc;
}
```

Best practise: set a class on the navigation element namely the ul.

```
<section>    
  <ul class="my-nav">
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
  </ul>
</section>

.my-nav {
  list-style-type: disc;
}
```

Comment: You can also can do article ul or section ul depending on which uls you would target.

Comment: Don't forget to override margin/padding, which are also reset.  Otherwise your bullet might be off-screen or cut-off by a parent element.

Comment: Specifically for the margin/padding, you'll want to add this to the ul CSS, not the li CSS, e.g.
`ul, ol {
list-style-type: disc;
padding-left: 20px;
}`

Answer (score 3):

You can gave a class for the `ul` element and define your own style.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="list">
  <h5>Just three steps:</h5>
  <ul>
    <li>Be awesome</li>
    <li>Stay awesome</li>
    <li>There is no step 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#list {
  width: 170px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  font-size: 20px;
}
#list ul {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
#list ul li {
  text-align: left;
  list-style: disc;
  margin: 10px 0px;
}
```

[***See demo***](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/thbqL/)

Comment: list-style: circle shows the bullet as the outline of a circle. Should be list-style: disc. It should be ul not ol.

Comment: @JohanVandenRym Thanks for noticing :). I have updated my answer and demo.

Answer (score 1):

I could not see the bullets either, they were just not on the visible page. Adding some padding fixed it:

```
<style>
.my-modal-list {
    list-style-type: disc;
    padding: 20px;
}
</style>

<ul class="my-modal-list">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```html
<ul style="list-style-type:disc;">
 <li>
   item1
 </li>
 <li>
   item2
 </li>
 <li>
   item3
 </li>
  <li>
   item4
  </li>
</ul>
```