# styling list elements not working Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

I have this list:

```
   <div id="modal-list">
        <ul class="docs-list">
          <li>stuff</li>
          <li>stuff 2</li>
          <li>stuff 3</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

And I have this styles:

```
#modal-list {
  list-style-type: disc;
}
```

I tried following [this advice in SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743852/how-to-display-a-bullet-list-using-ionic-framework) but didn't work.

But they don't work, I know this is a very simple problem so I'm baffled to why it's not working, also here's a demo: http://play.ionic.io/app/0180c18ca0a7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should to add `ul` to your style, because `modal-list` is only container with your list

for example you can do that :

```
#modal-list ul {
    list-style-type: disc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ul` has an class of `docs-list`, but your CSS is referencing an element of class `my-nav`. Change one or the other to match.

Comment: thanks but still not working as you can see here: http://play.ionic.io/app/0180c18ca0a7